# Saving XDocument to a zip file without running out of memory

Tags: c#, xml

I have a rather large XDocument, which I am trying to save to a ZipArchive. The code below works for me, but due to a limit on the amount of memory available for me, it fails with an OutOfMemoryException when the catalogXDocument.ToString() call is made.

Is there any way to save the XDocument to the ZipArchive without needing to have everything in memory?.

Code:

```
public Stream Zip(XDocument catalogXDocument)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        var catalogFile = archive.CreateEntry("Catalog.xml");

        using (var entryStream = catalogFile.Open())
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(entryStream))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(catalogXDocument.ToString());
        }
    }

    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return memoryStream;
}
```

Comment: If memory is a problem you can utilize more of disk space. [Save XDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.save) and zip file.

Comment: You can easily stream your XDocument to the ZipArchive (see Renat's answer). However `MemoryStream` is still in-memory, so you're just reducing the amount of data kept in-memory. You'd be better off getting rid of the `MemoryStream` entirely. It's hard to say how to do that since you're not showing how `Zip` is used, but it's likely that `Zip` should take a `Stream` to write to, rather than returning a `Stream`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work:

```
using (var entryStream = catalogFile.Open())
{
    catalogXDocument.Save(entryStream);
}
```